# MAC OSX LION: gcc on mac not compiling wget

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, wget, lynx

I am trying to install `lynx` / `wget` on my mac. and installation requires `gcc` to compile. I have `gcc` in my `/usr/local/bin` dir. I see that it is very much there.

```
           spankincubus:Downloads spankincubus$ gcc -v
           Using built-in specs.
           COLLECT_GCC=gcc
           COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0/4.6.1/lto-       wrapper
           Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0
           Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c++
           Thread model: posix
           gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
```

But when i run a configure utility for wget, i get an error. Any idea?? I'm not a `gcc` expert for the record.

```
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
**configure: error: in `/usr/local/bin/wget-1.14':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details**
```

This is how my gcc looks

```
  -rwxr-xr-x   1 root          wheel    91368 Jul 23  2011 gcov
  -rwxr-xr-x   1 root          wheel   462124 Jul 23  2011 cpp
  -rwxr-xr-x   1 root          wheel   462060 Jul 23  2011 gcc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, even though it appears that gcc exists; but does it point to a valid install? It still sounds like it is not installed properly and with an upgrade to Mountain Lion, all your open source tools have been scrubbed away and pushed to Xcode and must be manually installed if necessary.

Comment: Thank you!. SO if i understand you correctly, i should be looking to install gcc. Now i dont want to download Xcode but just gcc. I have found this source http://gcc.gnu.org. OR do i "have to" install Xcode ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/downloads/ -- you shouldn't have to subscribe to the paid program, but you'll need an apple id registered with the service.